# Função sendo chamada antes de ser chamada pela GUI

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Tenho um software que estou utilizando Tkinter como GUI, para receber alguns parametros que o usuario vai me passar.

Nesse software tenho 1 problema e uma duvida.

o problema é o seguinte, logo quando rodo o software a função process_files já é executada, e eu queria que ela só fosse executada quando eu clicasse no botão.

e o outro problema é como posso passar minha `variavel` `farm_name` e uma das opções selecionadas no `OptionMenu` para minha função `process_files`?, tentei só mandar como parametro, mas nao funciona.

```
from Tkinter import *
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog

window = Tk()


def process_files():
  #logic here.


#interface
farm_variable = StringVar()
farm_label = Label(window, text='Nome: ').pack()
farm_name = Entry(window, textvariable=farm_variable).pack()

year_label = Label(window, text='Ano: ').pack()
default_value = StringVar(window)
default_value.set(2018)

OptionMenu(window, default_value, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010).pack()

button_2 = Button(window, text='Processar')
button_2.bind("<Button-2>", process_files())
button_2.pack(side=RIGHT)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `button_2.bind("<Button-2>", process_files())`, você está chamando a função aqui

Comment: É a ideia não é que sonfosse executada qndo eu clicasse no botão 2?

Comment: Tire os parenteses, deixe apenas `button_2.bind("<Button-2>", process_files)`